# Button Readmore and three dots should not appear if the text is less than 150 characters

Tags: jquery

I have the this codes. This code adds three dots and X to all paragraphs. I want the X button and the three dots to showing only in paragraphs 150 characters long. I don't want a new script. This codes works perfectly for me. I just couldn't solve the 150 character event.

https://jsfiddle.net/xc9q3msa/

```js
var ReadMore = (function() {
  function ReadMore(limit, readMoreContainerElementSelector) {
    this.limit = limit;
    this.readMoreContainerElementSelector = readMoreContainerElementSelector;
    this.isFullTextShown = false;
    this.initializeReadMore();
  }
  ReadMore.prototype.initializeReadMore = function() {
    this.fullText = document.querySelector(this.readMoreContainerElementSelector + " .readMoreText").innerHTML;
    this.truncatedText = this.fullText.substr(0, this.limit) + ' ...';
    var that = this;
    document.querySelector(this.readMoreContainerElementSelector + " .readMoreButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
      that.performToogle();
    });
    this.performToogle();
  };
  ReadMore.prototype.performToogle = function() {
    var textToDisplay = "";
    var buttonText = "";
    this.isFullTextShown ? (textToDisplay = this.fullText, buttonText = "Daha Az Gör" ): (textToDisplay = this.truncatedText, buttonText = "Devamını Gör");
    this.isFullTextShown = !this.isFullTextShown;
    document.querySelector(this.readMoreContainerElementSelector + " .readMoreText").innerHTML = textToDisplay;
    document.querySelector(this.readMoreContainerElementSelector + " .readMoreButton").innerHTML = buttonText;
  };
  return ReadMore;
}());

var readmore = new ReadMore(150, "#log_readMoreContainer63");
var readmore = new ReadMore(150, "#log_readMoreContainer61");
var readmore = new ReadMore(150, "#log_readMoreContainer37");
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Poppins:300,400,500&subset=latin-ext);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700&subset=latin-ext);
body {
    background: var(--bg-image);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 background-size: cover;
}

.uyari svg, .btn-next svg, .btn-prev svg, .btn-last svg, .btn-first svg, .readtocont svg {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.uyari svg > path { fill: #ff2727; }
.index_button svg > path, .ist-tables svg > path, .data-date svg > path, .tuvalheader svg > path, .table-header svg > path, .ist-table svg > path, .copy_class > path, .print-borc svg > path, .next_nots > path, .prev_nots > path, .panel_header svg > path, .form-control svg > path, .address svg > path, .readtocont svg > path {
    fill: var(--panel-title-color);
}

  
.hastabilgipaneli {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.hastaveriekle {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.hastagor {
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    width: 30%;
    height: 202px;
    margin: 6% 4% 0 4%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2196078431372549);
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}

.panel {
    display: block;
    background: var(--panel-bg);
    width: 30%;
    margin: 4% auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px #00000038;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.panel_header {
    height: 64px;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-display: flex;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--panel-border);
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:'Play', sans-serif;
}
.panel_header .table-title {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: var(--panel-title-color);
}
.panel_header .actions {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.panel_header .actions a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.panel h3,
.hastagor h3,
.data-date h3 {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    color: var(--panel-title-color);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.hasta-tables {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.dipnot {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: var(--panel-title-color);
    padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
}
/*.hastagor span,
.panel span,
.data-date span {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: rgb(34, 167, 240);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}*/

.hastagor-header {
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 6% 4% 0 4%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2196078431372549);
    padding: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}



/* UYARI */

.uyari {
    width: 34%;
    height: 60px;
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 4% auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 19px;
}

.uyari img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.uyari span {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 5px;
}



/* Ä°nputlar */


.tuvalheader {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: var(--panel-bg);
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: var(--panel-title-color);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--panel-border);
}

.tuvalheader img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.tuvalbaslik {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.tuvalbody {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}

.hg-secenekler a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: initial;
}

.ortala {
    margin: 60px auto;
}

.hizala-12 {
    width: 100%;
}

.hizala-11 {
    width: 91.66666667%;
}

.hizala-10 {
    width: 83.33333333%;
}

.hizala-9 {
    width: 75%;
}

.hizala-8 {
    width: 66.66666667%;
}

.hizala-7 {
    width: 58.33333333%;
}

.hizala-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

.hizala-5 {
    width: 41.66666667%;
}

.hizala-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
}

.hizala-3 {
    width: 25%;
}
.hizala-3-1 {
    width: 20%;
}
.hizala-2 {
    width: 16.66666667%;
}

.hizala-1 {
    width: 8.33333333%;
}

.figurefix {
    display: unset;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.istatistik {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 90% !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2196078431372549);
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.ist-baslik {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: var(--panel-bg);
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: var(--panel-title-color);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--panel-border);
}

.ist-alticerik {
    display: block;
    background-color: var(--panel-bg);
    width: 100%;
    padding: 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid var(--panel-border);
}

.ist-alticerik>span {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: var(--table-text-color-2);
    font-weight: 700;
}

.ist-alticerik>span>span {
    color: var(--panel-subtitle-color);
    font-weight: 700;
}

.ist-alticerik-m {
    display: block;
    background-color: var(--panel-bg);
    width: 100%;
    color: #c3c6ce;
    padding: 15px;
}

.ist-alticerik-m>span {
    color: var(--panel-subtitle-color);
    font-weight: 700;
}

.ist-alticerik-m>span>span {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: var(--panel-title-color);
    font-weight: 700;
}

.ist-tables {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}

.ist-tables>.right {
    border-right: 2px solid var(--panel-border);
}

.ist-tables>.left {
    border-left: 2px solid var(--panel-border);
}

.ist-table {
    background-color: var(--panel-bg);
    padding: 25px;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.ist-table img, .ist-table svg {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.table_color_1 {
    color: var(--table-text-color-1);
 font-weight: 600;
}
.table_color_2 { /* red */
    color: var(--table-text-color-2);
 font-weight: 600;
}
.table_color_3 { /* green */
    color: var(--table-text-color-3);
 font-weight: 600;
}
.table_color_4 {
    color: var(--table-text-color-4);
 font-weight: 600;
}
.table_color_5 {
    color: var(--table-text-color-5);
 font-weight: 600;
}

.ist-count {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: var(--panel-title-color);
    font-weight: 400;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
    transition: all 0.35s;
}
.ist-count:hover {
    color: var(--panel-title-hover);
}

.ist-text {
    color: var(--panel-subtitle-color);
    font-weight: 500;
}

.ist-altext {
    font-style: italic;
    color: var(--panel-text-color);
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}


.data-date {
    display: inline-block;
    background: var(--panel-bg);
    width: 36%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2196078431372549);
}

.vericek {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%
}

/* not classes */
#hastanotlari-list > .list {
    display: block;
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 40px;
    padding-inline-end: 40px;
}
.hastanotlari {
    display: inline-block;
    background: var(--panel-bg);
    width: 50%;
    margin: 4% auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 2px #00000038;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 30px;
    color: var(--panel-text-color);
}
.hastanotlari h3 {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: var(--panel-title-color);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.not_icerik {
    list-style-type: none;
 text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.not_leftside {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 12px;
 text-align: center;
}
.not_content {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    vertical-align: top;
    max-width: 80%;
    min-height: 80px;
    text-align: left;
    border-left: 4px solid var(--panel-border);
}
.readMoreButton {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 29px;
    padding-left: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: var(--panel-title-color);
    font-weight: 700;
}
.not_contentext {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 12px;
}
.not_date {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: var(--panel-title-color);
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.none_not {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 36px;
}

.pagination > li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.pagination > li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-block-start: 1em;
    margin-block-end: 1em;
    margin-inline-start: 0px;
    margin-inline-end: 0px;
    padding-inline-start: 0px;
}
.pagination > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--panel-subtitle-color);
    font-weight: 500;
}
.pagination > li > a:hover {
    color: var(--panel-subtitle-color-hover);
}
.pagination .active > a {
    color: var(--panel-subtitle-color-hover);
}
.btn-first {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.btn-next {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.btn-prev {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.btn-last {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.btn-next svg > path, .btn-prev svg > path, .btn-last svg > path, .btn-first svg > path {
    fill: var(--panel-subtitle-color);
    stroke-width: .5;
    stroke: var(--panel-subtitle-color);
}
.btn-next svg:hover > path, .btn-prev svg:hover > path, .btn-last svg:hover > path, .btn-first svg:hover > path {
    fill: var(--panel-subtitle-color-hover);
}

/* end */

.print-borc {
 position: absolute;
 top: 6px;
 right: 0;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
    background-color: var(--panel-bg);
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 outline: none;
 padding: 6px 0;
 min-width: 160px;
 z-index: 1;
 text-align: left;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
 padding-bottom: 4px;
 padding-top: 4px;
 color: #202124;
 padding-left: 30px;
 padding-right: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
 white-space: nowrap;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 font-size: .875rem !important;
 letter-spacing: .2px !important;
 text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a > img { 
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-right: 6px;
}
.dropdown-span { 
 font-size: 14px !important;
    text-transform: capitalize !important;
    color: var(--panel-text-color);
    text-align: left !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
 margin-left: 5px !important;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: var(--dropdown-line-hover)}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
.reverse-right {
 right: 0 !important;
 left: auto;
}
.reverse-bottom {
 bottom: 100% !important;
 top: auto;
}
.copy_class {
 vertical-align: middle;
 margin-left: 5px;
 cursor: pointer;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
}
.sec_dropdown {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 34px;
}
.sec_dropdown path {
    fill: var(--table-options-color);
}

/* end */
/* dark light switch css */

.theme-switch-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
}
.theme-switch {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 26px;
    position: relative;
    width: 52px;
}
.theme-switch input {
    display:none;
}
.slider {
    background-color: #ccc0;
    border: 3px solid #a5a4a4;
    bottom: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: .4s;
}
.slider:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #a5a4a4;
    bottom: 1.8px;
    left: 3px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transition: .4s;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
#darklightswitch:checked + .slider {
    border: 3px solid #3694ff;
}
#darklightswitch:checked + .slider:before {
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 0 0 #3694ff;
    background: 0 0;
    left: 21.1px;
}
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
}

/* end */

.table-adsoyad {
    color: var(--panel-text-color);
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* sweetalert2 custom css */

.swal2-confirm a {
 color: var(--panel-text-color);
    text-decoration: none;
}
[data-theme="dark"] {
    --bg-color: rgba(47, 47, 47, 1);
    --bg-image: url(https://panel.davidturkiye.com/img/body-bg.png) no-repeat top center fixed;
    --panel-bg: rgba(30, 38, 44, 1);
    --panel-bg-hover: rgba(47, 58, 66, 1);
    --panel-border: rgba(255, 165, 0, 1);
    --panel-title-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 1);
    --panel-title-hover: rgba(201, 203, 204, 1);
    --panel-subtitle-color: rgba(195, 198, 206, 1);
    --panel-subtitle-color-hover: rgba(255, 165, 0, 1);
    --panel-text-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    --panel-button-bg: rgba(220, 74, 74, 1);
    --panel-button-hover-bg: rgba(216, 53, 53, 1);
    --panel-button-text-color: rgba(255, 215, 248, 1);
    --panel-button-text-hover-color: rgba(255, 215, 248, 1);
    --input-bg: rgba(26, 32, 37, 1);
    --input-border-color: rgba(54, 148, 255, 1);
    --input-label-color: rgba(94, 100, 111, 1);
    --input-label-color-focus: rgba(54, 148, 255, 1);
    --input-text-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    --search-input-bg: rgba(30, 38, 44, 1);
    --table-shorting: rgba(255, 165, 0, 1);
    --table-text-color-1: rgba(65, 125, 158, 1);
    --table-text-color-2: rgba(255, 98, 98, 1);
    --table-text-color-3: rgba(53, 142, 101, 1);
    --table-text-color-4: rgba(62, 175, 164, 1);
    --table-text-color-5: rgba(64, 197, 123, 1);
    --table-options-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 1);
    --table-options-hover-color: rgba(88, 71, 32, 1);
    --dropdown-line-hover: rgba(99, 71, 71, 1);
    --active-color: rgba(15, 152, 15, 1);
    --passive-color: rgba(191, 30, 14, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body data-theme="dark"><div class="hastabilgipaneli">
<div class="hastanotlari" style="display: inline-block;">
<div class="panel_header">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"> 
<path d="M14,10V4.5L19.5,10M5,3C3.89,3 3,3.89 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V9L15,3H5Z"></path>
</svg>
<span class="table-title">Hasta Logları</span>
</div>
<div id="hastanotlari-list">
<ul class="list">
<li name="not-icerik-list" class="not_icerik">
<div class="not_leftside">
<span class="not_date">29.02.2020<br>11:08:36</span>
<div class="dropdown"> 
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="secenekler dropbtn" style="display: block; margin: auto; position: unset;"> 
<path d="M12,16A2,2 0 0,1 14,18A2,2 0 0,1 12,20A2,2 0 0,1 10,18A2,2 0 0,1 12,16M12,10A2,2 0 0,1 14,12A2,2 0 0,1 12,14A2,2 0 0,1 10,12A2,2 0 0,1 12,10M12,4A2,2 0 0,1 14,6A2,2 0 0,1 12,8A2,2 0 0,1 10,6A2,2 0 0,1 12,4Z"></path>
</svg>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="notduzenle.php?nid=63">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="sec_dropdown"> 
<path d="M20.71,7.04C21.1,6.65 21.1,6 20.71,5.63L18.37,3.29C18,2.9 17.35,2.9 16.96,3.29L15.12,5.12L18.87,8.87M3,17.25V21H6.75L17.81,9.93L14.06,6.18L3,17.25Z"></path>
</svg>
<span class="dropdown-span">Not Düzenle</span>
</a>
<a onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; NotSil('63')">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="sec_dropdown"> 
<path d="M19,4H15.5L14.5,3H9.5L8.5,4H5V6H19M6,19A2,2 0 0,0 8,21H16A2,2 0 0,0 18,19V7H6V19Z" style="fill: #ff0000 !important;"></path>
</svg>
<span class="dropdown-span">Notu Sil</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="not_content" id="log_readMoreContainer63">
<span class="not_contentext readMoreText">
Deneme not.</span>
<a class="readMoreButton">Devamını Gör</a>
</div>
</li>
<li name="not-icerik-list" class="not_icerik">
<div class="not_leftside">
<span class="not_date">28.02.2020<br>18:45:26</span>
<div class="dropdown"> 
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="secenekler dropbtn" style="display: block; margin: auto; position: unset;"> 
<path d="M12,16A2,2 0 0,1 14,18A2,2 0 0,1 12,20A2,2 0 0,1 10,18A2,2 0 0,1 12,16M12,10A2,2 0 0,1 14,12A2,2 0 0,1 12,14A2,2 0 0,1 10,12A2,2 0 0,1 12,10M12,4A2,2 0 0,1 14,6A2,2 0 0,1 12,8A2,2 0 0,1 10,6A2,2 0 0,1 12,4Z"></path>
</svg>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="notduzenle.php?nid=61">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="sec_dropdown"> 
<path d="M20.71,7.04C21.1,6.65 21.1,6 20.71,5.63L18.37,3.29C18,2.9 17.35,2.9 16.96,3.29L15.12,5.12L18.87,8.87M3,17.25V21H6.75L17.81,9.93L14.06,6.18L3,17.25Z"></path>
</svg>
<span class="dropdown-span">Not Düzenle</span>
</a>
<a onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; NotSil('61')">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="sec_dropdown"> 
<path d="M19,4H15.5L14.5,3H9.5L8.5,4H5V6H19M6,19A2,2 0 0,0 8,21H16A2,2 0 0,0 18,19V7H6V19Z" style="fill: #ff0000 !important;"></path>
</svg>
<span class="dropdown-span">Notu Sil</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="not_content" id="log_readMoreContainer61">
<span class="not_contentext readMoreText">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut faucibus, diam ut condimentum posuere, orci libero molestie nunc, a laoreet nunc ante ut justo. Donec imperdiet est eu lobortis mattis. Ut sit amet metus id erat posuere laoreet eget non dui. Phasellus dui est, vehicula nec enim vel, ultricies finibus diam. Donec interdum tincidunt nibh ac tristique. Sed ultricies risus auctor, fermentum lacus id, varius quam. Sed porta quis lectus nec consectetur. Mauris blandit tortor et nisi placerat ultricies. Aenean ultricies mi at dui tincidunt accumsan.</span>
<a class="readMoreButton">Devamını Gör</a>
</div>
</li>
<li name="not-icerik-list" class="not_icerik">
<div class="not_leftside">
<span class="not_date">25.02.2020<br>18:07:48</span>
<div class="dropdown"> 
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="secenekler dropbtn" style="display: block; margin: auto; position: unset;"> 
<path d="M12,16A2,2 0 0,1 14,18A2,2 0 0,1 12,20A2,2 0 0,1 10,18A2,2 0 0,1 12,16M12,10A2,2 0 0,1 14,12A2,2 0 0,1 12,14A2,2 0 0,1 10,12A2,2 0 0,1 12,10M12,4A2,2 0 0,1 14,6A2,2 0 0,1 12,8A2,2 0 0,1 10,6A2,2 0 0,1 12,4Z"></path>
</svg>
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
<a href="notduzenle.php?nid=37">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="sec_dropdown"> 
<path d="M20.71,7.04C21.1,6.65 21.1,6 20.71,5.63L18.37,3.29C18,2.9 17.35,2.9 16.96,3.29L15.12,5.12L18.87,8.87M3,17.25V21H6.75L17.81,9.93L14.06,6.18L3,17.25Z"></path>
</svg>
<span class="dropdown-span">Not Düzenle</span>
</a>
<a onclick="if (!window.__cfRLUnblockHandlers) return false; NotSil('37')">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="sec_dropdown"> 
<path d="M19,4H15.5L14.5,3H9.5L8.5,4H5V6H19M6,19A2,2 0 0,0 8,21H16A2,2 0 0,0 18,19V7H6V19Z" style="fill: #ff0000 !important;"></path>
</svg>
<span class="dropdown-span">Notu Sil</span>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="not_content" id="log_readMoreContainer37">
<span class="not_contentext readMoreText">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut faucibus, diam ut condimentum posuere, orci libero molestie nunc, a laoreet nunc ante ut justo. Donec imperdiet est eu lobortis mattis. Ut sit amet metus id erat posuere laoreet eget non dui. Phasellus dui est, vehicula nec enim vel, ultricies finibus diam. Donec interdum tincidunt nibh ac tristique. Sed ultricies risus auctor, fermentum lacus id, varius quam. Sed porta quis lectus nec consectetur. Mauris blandit tortor et nisi placerat ultricies. Aenean ultricies mi at dui tincidunt accumsan.</span>
<a class="readMoreButton">Devamını Gör</a>
</div>
</li>
</ul> <div class="nav"><div class="btn-first"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M18.41,7.41L17,6L11,12L17,18L18.41,16.59L13.83,12L18.41,7.41M12.41,7.41L11,6L5,12L11,18L12.41,16.59L7.83,12L12.41,7.41Z"></path></svg></div><div class="btn-prev"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M15.41,16.58L10.83,12L15.41,7.41L14,6L8,12L14,18L15.41,16.58Z"></path></svg></div>
<ul class="pagination"></ul>
<div class="btn-next"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M8.59,16.58L13.17,12L8.59,7.41L10,6L16,12L10,18L8.59,16.58Z"></path></svg></div><div class="btn-last"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5.59,7.41L7,6L13,12L7,18L5.59,16.59L10.17,12L5.59,7.41M11.59,7.41L13,6L19,12L13,18L11.59,16.59L16.17,12L11.59,7.41Z"></path></svg></div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you tag this with `jquery` when you don't use any feature of jQuery? Instead, it is more important to tag with `javascript`, which is relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
  ReadMore.prototype.initializeReadMore = function() {
    this.fullText = document.querySelector(this.readMoreContainerElementSelector + " .readMoreText").innerHTML;
```

To this:

```
  ReadMore.prototype.initializeReadMore = function() {
    this.fullText = document.querySelector(this.readMoreContainerElementSelector + " .readMoreText").innerHTML;
    if (this.fullText.length <= this.limit) {
         document.querySelector(this.readMoreContainerElementSelector + " .readMoreButton").style.display = "none";
         return;
    }
```

NB: although you tell us that your script is perfect, you really should not use `innerHTML`, but `textContent`, as HTML entities should not count with their entity-lengths, but their text-representation-lengths.

Comment: What is your suggestion? BTW, thanks for the solution.

Comment: My suggestion is to use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. And if you want to use jQuery, then don't use `document.querySelector`, but `$`, and then `$(selector).text(text)`, ...etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will do.